# Carousel swipe functionality on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, carousel

I need to implement carousel swipe functionality on touch devices using JS/jQuery without any other libraries. For this, i have written a function as follows:

```
$(".carousel-inner").on("touchstart", function(event){
        var xClick = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    $(this).one("touchmove", function(event){
        var xMove = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
        if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) > 5 ){
            $(this).carousel('next');
        }
        else if( Math.floor(xClick - xMove) < -5 ){
            $(this).carousel('prev');
        }
    });
    $(".carousel").on("touchend", function(){
            $(this).off("touchmove");
    });
});
```

This is working fine, but the problem is that the "sliding" is not smooth. The next image just appears based on the direction of the swipe. How can i make the transition between the slides appear smoother? Please suggest how i can achieve this without using any libraries. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

i am little bit late but bootstrap has this functionality from v4.3 with `data-touch="true"`, also make sure you set `data-ride="carousel"`

```
<div id="carouselShowcaseSlider" class="carousel slide" data-touch="true" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
```

- [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#options)
- [Github thread](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30700)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make smooth sliding with CSS transitions.